# Run functions from the list sequentially until one resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have list of functions which returns promises. I want them to be run sequentially until at least one of them resolves. And if one of them resolves all others should not be executed.

The algorithm should be the following:

Run first function, if it resolves quit with returned value, otherwise run second function if it resolves quit with returned value and so on.

Is it possible to achieve that with promises? I'm using Bluebird library.

## Desired pseudo code

```js
.run(getUserFromFileById(id))
.run(getUserFromFileByEmail(email))
.run(getUserFromDatabaseById(id))
.run(getUserFromDatabaseByEmail(email))
// ...
.gotResult(function (user) {
  console.log('We have user!');
})
.allFailed(function () {
  console.log('No joy!');
})
```

Comment: By "otherwise" you mean "if it rejects"?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about rejecting initially, but now, I'm not quite sure, maybe I should resolve with null value instead? I have control over these functions.

Comment: I think reject is the way to go - although, from my answer, you can see I was initially thinking the other way - I think my answer covers both schools of thought though :p

Comment: Depends. Was getting a result expected, and is having none an error? What other errors (exceptions) may happen? And do you want to treat them the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Looking at it more closely, this isn't the best way*

assuming all **your** functions below **resolve** to a user if they can, or resolve to *falsey* (*false, '', null, undefined, 0* etc) if they can't, and **don't** reject/throw on not finding the user

```
getUserFromFileById(id).then(function(user) {
    return user || getUserFromFileByEmail(email)
}).then(function(user) {
    return user || getUserFromDatabaseById(id)
}).then(function(user) {
    return user || getUserFromDatabaseByEmail(email)
}).then(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log('woot got user');
    }
    else {
        console.log('no user');
        throw 'no user';
    }
}).catch(function(fail) {
    console.log('something went wrong');
});
```

Having looked at it, this way makes more sense

This assumes your functions **resolve** a *user* otherwise **reject** the promise - I think this makes more sense, generally? no?

```
getUserFromFileById(id).catch(function() {
    return getUserFromFileByEmail(email);
}).catch(function() {
    return getUserFromDatabaseById(id);
}).catch(function() {
    return getUserFromDatabaseByEmail(email);
}).then(function(user) {
    console.log('woot got user', user);
}, function(fail) {
    console.log('something went wrong', fail);
});
```

Comment: @Bergi - thanks, that's even cleaner!! (it's a good day when you learn something, I never considered chaining catch's like that)

Comment: Well `.then(null, …)` is exactly the same as `.catch(…)` (in ES6 at least)

Comment: I've always thought there was some "finality" about catch though, but you are, of course, correct, seeing catch's chained like that is still a bit foreign in a _try/catch_ sense

Comment: `try`/`catch` has never been the best analogy to promises anyway imo, as it does not provide a way to distinguish the non-error case

Comment: Thank you guys for an elegant solution! I was actually thinking about using the catches in such a manner, however, I wasn't sure if it's OK.